# 2 in 1 Button like Dual-Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can't seem to create a button that look something like this one (See Picture).[image]

I've tried to combine a grid, 2 ellipses and 2 textblocks to something that looks like it, but can't get the two different buttons to look right..

It's generally a button split in half and then converted into 2 separate buttons, S button and A button..

Any input would be very helpful..

Comment: Sounds like all you really need is 2 buttons right next to each other. Button 1 being the left semi-circle and button 2 being the right, then just style either the content or the template of the buttons to look how you want.

Comment: Did you even read any of the answers, before posting a comment??

Comment: You haven't flagged a single one of them as the answer you're looking for. If one of them answered your question, check it as your chosen answer, otherwise keep expecting people coming in and commenting on this, buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering with 1 grid, 2 ellipses and 2 textblocks I got it to work..
And 2 Viewboxes for resizing.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Dual_Button.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dual_Button"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dual Button" Height="260" Width="260">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubBack" Color="#FFD1FF00"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AudioBack" Color="#FF00C5FF"/>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse x:Name="sub_Background" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" Fill="{DynamicResource SubBack}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Sub" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Click="btn_Sub_Click" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" MouseEnter="btn_Sub_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btn_Sub_MouseLeave">
            <Viewbox Margin="25,10,10,25">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="S"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Audio_Background" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" Fill="{DynamicResource AudioBack}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Audio" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" Click="btn_Audio_Click" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" MouseEnter="btn_Audio_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btn_Audio_MouseLeave">
            <Viewbox Margin="10,10,25,25">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="A"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void btn_Sub_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try { sub_Background.Fill = Brushes.Red; } catch { }
        }
        void btn_Sub_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try { sub_Background.Fill = (Brush)FindResource("SubBack"); } catch { }
        }
        void btn_Sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Subtitles");
        }

        void btn_Audio_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try { Audio_Background.Fill = Brushes.Purple; } catch { }
        }
        void btn_Audio_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try { Audio_Background.Fill = (Brush)FindResource("AudioBack"); } catch { }
        }
        void btn_Audio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Audio");
        }
    }
```

This is my result: And it's scale able..

[image]

When the mouse enters the S button the half Circle will change into Red.
When the mouse enters the A button the half Circle will change into Purple.

Answer (score 1):

I have probably managed to create what you were looking for. Please note, that this requires **further work** since a lot of functionality was not implemented. What I did, was just creating a "DualButton" that has separate clickable parts and looks as you have provided.

You can work out your own style and functionality based off my example.

First, how it looks:

[image: Dual Button]

Now, to the code. I defined it as a userControl for easier management and reusability without clunkying the XAML too much.

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.DualButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="Lime" >
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="150,0">
                                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True"
                            Size="50, 50"
                            Point="150, 300"
                            SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" />
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <TextBlock Margin="49,46,171,83" FontSize="150" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White">S</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_2">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="Blue" >
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="150,0">
                                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True"
                            Size="50, 50"
                            Point="150, 300"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <TextBlock Margin="162,47,41,84" FontSize="150" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Width="97">A</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

So, what is actually happening here?

First, there is the layout grid of course. It contains two `buttons`, that have their template set to `PathGeometry` to create an Ellipse. (Here is already some place for improvement - I used fixed values, so the `button` won't be really scalable. Try to connect these properties with a `grid` size)

Then there is a `textBlock` for obvious letters on the button halves. Again, I didn't bother too much with placing, I just dragged them around so they looked nice. You can work out this on your own too (I hope :D )

**Now, with the code-behind:**

```
public partial class DualButton : UserControl
{
    public DualButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent =
EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(DualButton));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click
    {
        add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Left");
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Right");
    }
}
```

Here we are adding a `RoutedEvent` to make our button actually clickable. I also added some event handlers to check if everything worked as expected (it did!)

Again, this is just a quick example and is by no means optimized. There is a lot of space for improvement. I just wanted to push you in the right direction.

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Take a look at my own answer.. And see if you like it.. The only think I don't like about your answer is the Path you use for the half circle shapes..

Comment: I like your answer too. As for the path, I would disagree, since with correct bindings it could produce any shape desired (not just ellipses). Your viewBox idea is really good too, and your answer is much more MVVM patterned than mine, which is great. To be honest, I thought you had no Idea how to approach the problem, so I just created a quick scratch example thats hard-coded and didn't bother much about the style it was written in. I guess both our answers have pros and cons, but for now yours is more developed :)

Comment: I'm no newbie, Even if I can do it myself sometimes I like to see how others would do.. And I gave you +1 in vote since your answer wasn't bad..

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Good luck with your new button ^^